# Resetting a dynamic vertex buffer after lost device

Tags: c++, directx

I'm using a dynamic vertex buffer to render some terrain. As all resources that use the `D3DPOOL_DEFAULT` flag need to be released before you can reset the device, I have a method that takes care of calling the `Release` function on my vertex buffer.
The thing is, my buffer is then no longer usable since it's been released, and calling `CreateVertexBuffer` to recreate it after the device was reset causes my app to crash.
How can I recreate my vertex buffer after I've reset the device?

I've also noticed that after I release the buffer, I can still use it even though I set the pointer to 0 after releasing it.

Here is the code I'm using:

Before I call `Reset` on the D3D device, I call `onLostDevice` for all resources that need to be released:

```
void Water::onLostDevice()
{
    this->mVertexBuffer->Release();
    this->mVertexBuffer = 0;
}
```

And after `Reset` was called on the device, I call `onResetDevice` on all the resources in the default mem pool:

```
void Water::onResetDevice(IDirect3DDevice9 *device)
{
    device->CreateVertexBuffer(totalVertices * sizeof(d3df::VertexPositionColor),
    D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC | D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY, 0, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &mVertexBuffer, 0);
}
```

The `onResetDevice` call causes the crash, yet I do need a way to get my vertex buffer back so that I can use it.

By the way, it crashes when I resize the window or go fullscreen.

Comment: I think that you will need to post some code.

Comment: I added some code, but it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: @__dominic: Did you try running against the debug runtime and seeing what errors it throws?

Comment: When you write that you "can still use [the vertex buffer] ... even though I set the pointer to 0", I hope that you know that that is really bad. By using the buffer at address `(IDirect3DVertexBuffer9*) 0`, you are dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: Are you checking the return value of the call to `IDirect3DDevice9::Reset` to make sure that it succeeded? Is it possible that you have multiple references to a vertex buffer? I.e. what is the return value of `this->mVertexBuffer->Release()`?

Comment: @DeadMG yep, I'm running it with tge d3d debug runtime, the only stack trace I get traces back to a disassembly file.

@Daniel Trebbien yeah I know, I'm just lucky the data is still there. the call to Reset succeeds, and I'm also reseting some fonts and stuff, it only crashes if I call CreateVertexBuffer in the Water::onResetDevice method. And also, this->mVertexBuffer->Release() returns a ref count of 0.

Comment: Maybe the D3D device does not support the `D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC` usage? Try using the `CheckDeviceFormat` method to make sure that `D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC` is supported.

Comment: Maybe there is not enough memory available. What is the value of `totalVertices` when the call to `CreateVertexBuffer` causes the program to crash?

Comment: I've tested for dynamic buffer support, and the device supports it. The buffer has a grid of 50*50 vertices.

Comment: Maybe `device` is a bad pointer. Before calling `CreateVertexBuffer` within `onResetDevice`, try calling some other method (e.g. `GetDirect3D`).

Comment: It's not been said here yet so I will say it (for anyone else reading this): Sounds obvious but before releasing the vertex buffer you should test to see if it is not NULL; e.g ..
`if(this->m_VertexBuffer != NULL) this->m_VertexBuffer->Release();`

Otherwise you will also get a crash :)